# one-cocycles over finite groups

Tags: group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $S$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let
$\alpha$ be a one-cocycle $G\to M$ for some $G$-module $M$, and
suppose that $Res_{S}^{G}\alpha=0$. For $g\in G$, and $S^{g}=gSg^{-1}$,
$Res_{S^{g}}^{G}\alpha$ is a coboundary. But according to Weiss,
Cohomology of Groups, if $\tau=gsg^{-1}\in S^{g}$ then $\alpha_{\tau}=g\alpha_{s}$

which would mean that $\alpha_{\tau}=0$. I must be misunderstanding
something.

Comment: What is $\alpha_s$ resp. $\alpha_\tau$ ?

Comment: Which page in Weiss?

Comment: $\alpha$\_s = $\alpha$(s)

Comment: A 1-cocycle is just a derivation. Hence $\alpha(\tau)=g\alpha(s) + (1-\tau)\alpha(g)$. Here $\tau \mapsto (1-\tau)\alpha(g)$ is an inner derivation (=1-coboundary). Perhaps Weiss' equation has to be understood "modulo a coboundary" ?

Comment: I think you are right, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I trhink you mixed $\alpha$ and ${\rm con}\alpha$. In fact,
${\rm con_g}\alpha (\tau) =g\alpha (g^{-1}sg)$, and I don't see any
contradiction here.